# UIPickerView for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a **Unit Converter** app using a pickerview with three components and a plist. The first component is category component and the remaining are units components. What i need is when i select an item in category component the remaining two components should get the values regarding that particular component. For this to work how i need to take a plist? Can some one help me on this?

Comment: What to you mean by "For this to work how i need to take a plist?".

Answer (score 1):

First your que. is not pretty clear, I mean , do u fetching the data using webservice or what...? plist..it is not necessary

---

all stuff that u've to play with delegates methods for e.g.

1)

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 

{

}
```

tells how many component u want to add.like categories/unit1/unit2/bla..bla...bla

2)

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger) component

{

}
```

tells what u hv to do with rows.

3)

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

}
```

thats it

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean with the plist... But:

For the context dependent presentation of the two other values you should have a look into `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` of `UIPickerViewDelegate`. There you can react of the change of the value in the first component.

Comment: Ok whats the method to display values in component? please help me in detail